# How do I convert a date into epoch time in Perl?

Tags: perl, datetime, date, epoch

Solaris 10 doesn't seem to like me a lot.
I am trying to run a simple script to accept date and return epoch of that date:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use Time::ParseDate;

my $date1 = "Mon Mar 27 05:54:08 CDT 2009";

#Convert to seconds since start of epoch
my $time1 = parsedate($date1);
print $time1;
```

Works perfectly fine on RHEL box, but gets screwed on Solaris(both have 5.8.8 Perl), giving the following error message.

Can't locate Date/Parse.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/perl5/5.8.4/lib/sun4-solaris-64int /usr/perl5/5.8.4/lib /usr/perl5/site_perl/5.8.4/sun4-solaris-64int /usr/perl5/site_perl/5.8.4 /usr/perl5/site_perl /usr/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.4/sun4-solaris-64int /usr/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.4 /usr/perl5/vendor_perl .) at try1.pl line 3.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at try1.pl line 3.

Whats wrong here?.. how to correct this?.

Oh.. almost forgot, I cannot alter/install/modify anything on this Solaris box, this script needs to be shipped to a customer who runs Solaris 10!. So asking him to install a module is definitely not an option. :(

Comment: By the way, why are you chomping $date1? It has no newline character in it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message says it cannot find the module Date::Parse in your Perl library include path (**@INC**).

The module is available from [CPAN](http://www.cpan.org/) (Comprehensive Perl Archive Network). If you need a Perl module that is not included in the base install, typically (>90%) it is available from CPAN, the *de facto* Perl module archive site.

Your question is addressed with the CPAN module (the CPAN module is used to retrieve modules from CPAN) documentation. I suggest starting with [FAQ](http://search.cpan.org/~rgarcia/perl-5.6.2/lib/CPAN.pm#FAQ) question 5, "I am not root, how can I install a module in a personal directory?"

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to do this with Time::Piece which is core on Perl **5.10** (correction here: it's not core in 5.8). Here's an example from my machine. See `man strftime`, `man strptime` and `perldoc Time::Piece`. In the `Time::Piece` docs, you want to check the section *Date Parsing*. (The conversion details may vary on a Solaris machine. I'm on OS X right now at work.)

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::Piece;

my $date = Time::Piece->strptime("Tue Apr 7 12:46:59 2009",
  "%a %b %e %H:%M:%S %Y");
my $epoch_date = $date->epoch;

print "$epoch_date\n";
```

**Edit**: The parser chokes on CDT (%Z doesn't appear to recognize it), so you may need to do this in two steps. The following works for me:

```
my $string = "Mon Mar 27 05:54:08 CDT 2009";
$string =~ s/CDT/-0500/; # Replace timezone with offset from UTC
my $date = Time::Piece->strptime($string, "%a %b %e %H:%M:%S %z %Y");
my $epoch_date = $date->epoch;

print "$epoch_date\n";
```

However, now we have the additional problem of CDT => -0500 versus CST => -0600. I officially hate daylight savings.

Comment: Mesg on RHEL & Solaris
Can't locate Time/Piece.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/lib /usr/lib/site_perl /usr/local/sendmail/perl-1.3/lib/5.8.3/i686-linux  /usr/local/sendmail/perl-1.3/lib/site_perl/5.8.3/i686-linux  /usr/local/sendmail/perl-1.3/lib/site_perl .) at try2.pl line 4.

Comment: According to Module::CoreList, Time::Piece did not become a core module until 5.9.5, which was part of the development series leading up to Perl 5.10. It works with 5.8, but it didn't ship with it. (OS X might have included it as an extra.)

Comment: No, actually, you're right. I was not careful enough about which core modules I was checking. It's not present in 5.8. Apologies for the mistake.

Answer (score 4):

Since you need to ship the program to a customer who will not install modules for you, you will need to use [PAR::Packer](http://search.cpan.org/dist/PAR-Packer/lib/PAR/Packer.pm) to create a native executable that contains all of your dependencies (or use only Core Modules).

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure that's the right error message?  [Date::Parse](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Date::Parse) is an entirely separate module from [Time::ParseDate](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Time::ParseDate).  They provide similar functionality, but don't use each other.

You can use [Module::CoreList](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Module-CoreList/) to get a list of the modules that shipped with 5.8.8.  I don't know if Solaris 10 included any additional modules.

You might have to copy the guts out of a suitable module and paste it into your script.  (Remember that a Perl file may have multiple `package` statements.)

Comment: I was basically trying solutions provided here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/411740/how-can-i-parse-dates-and-convert-time-zones-in-perl

I was getting similar error messages of the module not being present and hence may be pasted the wrong one here. Sorry bout that. But the problem remains :|

Answer (score 1):

Old thread, but this may help people with the same problem. Use the timelocal function in the standard Time::Local module. See  [perlfaq 4](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-can-I-take-a-string-and-turn-it-into-epoch-seconds?)

Answer (score 0):

> Solaris 10 doesn't seem to like me a lot. I am trying to run a simple script to accept date and return epoch of that date

Silly question, but what is the source of the input date string? If the string is fetched from the system your code can be a lot more simple.