# R: Using regular expression to swap strings separated by a comma

Tags: r, regex

So I have this list of names:

```
names <- c("stewart,pat", "peterson,greg")
```

from which I extract only the `lastname,firstname` items with the following regular expression:

```
myregexpr <- "(\\w+),(\\w+)?"
str_view(str_extract_all(names, myregexpr), myregexpr)
```

This yields a view like:

`stewart,pat`

`peterson,greg`

**My question:** Is there a way for me to write the regular expression such that the result would instead look like:

`pat_stewart`

`greg_peterson`

i.e. where the result of is `first_last`? I believe there is a way to do it as I've seen on other, [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023334/how-can-i-reorder-substrings-in-a-string).  I've tried:

```
myregexpr <- "(\\w+),(\\w+)?\\2_\\1"
```

but that returns only `character(0)'. I've attempted many versions - some of which crash R studio.  Any ideas?

Comment: Like `gsub("(.*),(.*)", "\\2_\\1", names)`?

Comment: It's possible (though more complicated) to avoid regex: `sapply(strsplit(names, ','), function(s){paste(rev(s), collapse = '_')})`

Comment: I'm looking for a solution that's like the one [I linked to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023334/how-can-i-reorder-substrings-in-a-string) where the reordered is the result.

Comment: @rich-scriven - using `gsub` worked well - also: your regular expression is slicker than mine: `"(.*),(.*)"` - thanks!