# Regular Expression to match a valid day in a date

Tags: regex, perl, validation, date

I need help coming up with a regex to make sure the user enters a valid date
The string will be in the format of `mm/dd/yyyy`

Here is what I have come up with so far.

```
/\[1-9]|0[1-9]|1[0-2]\/\d{1,2}\/19|20\d\d/
```

I have validated the regex where the user cannot enter a day higher than 12 and the years have to start with either "19" or "20". What I am having trouble is figuring out some logic for validating the day. The day should not go over 31.

Comment: A regex seems like a strange tool for this problem.  Can you not convert the text to a date and check its values?

Comment: While this could theoretically be done, a regex that handled the correct number of days for each month (including leap years) would be insanely complex.  Why not just split the date up and test each component?  (Or better yet, use one of the many date parsers on CPAN.)

Comment: @Zerobu, why do you ask the same question again than a year ago??? [questions/2573466/matching-a-date-in-perl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573466/matching-a-date-in-perl). OK, a year ago you didn't got a regex answer, but I hope you see from @Seth answer regex is not useful to validate a date.

Comment: If I wanted all conditions such as the leap year, then I would have said so

Comment: @Zerobu, my point is simply that most people start thinking they just need a simple regex for a date string, but end up needing something "real".  If that's not the case for you, no problem :)  If it is, well, my answer will still be here when you need it!

Comment: Zerobu: you said so: "a regex to make sure the user enters a valid date".

Comment: Unless using a Regex is a static/inmutable requirement, consider using other approaches, like .net's DateTime.TryParseExact(value, format)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Regex for 0-31:

```
(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])
```

Or if you don't want days with a preceding zero (e.g. 05):

```
([1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])
```

Comment: Thanks apparently the other posters had a hard time figuring out what i was looking for, even though I already said what I needed

Comment: That's because the date won't necessarily be valid. It won't, for example, reject 31 February 2011. Regex it the wrong tool for this.

Comment: was 1974 a leap year? what about 2000?

Comment: Wouldn't this allow a value of '00'?

Comment: This doesn't allow for days ending in zero -- "10" or "20".

Comment: Doesn't work for 10 and 20. See: `gawk 'BEGIN{ for(i=0;i<=32;i++){ if (i ~ /^([0-2]?[1-9]|3[01])$/){print i "yes"}else {print i "no"} } }'`

Comment: The first one works fine now; but I am seeing that the 2nd regex matches 0, 32, and misses to match double digit numbers.. Could you kindly check - [test](http://regexr.com?37lbr). Also you could refer to [my post below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20473796/985766). Cheers

Answer (score 16):

- As many have noted above, if we want to validate the date as a whole then a RegEx is a very poor choice.
- But if we want to *match a pattern of numbers*, in this case from `01-31` then RegEx is fine so long as there is some backend logic that validates the date as a whole, if so desired.
- I see the expected answer currently fails for 10, 20.

  - Test:  `gawk 'BEGIN{ for(i=0;i<=32;i++){ if (i ~ /^([0-2]?[1-9]|3[01])$/){print i " yes"}else {print i " no"} } }`
  - This can be corrected as follows: `^([0-2]?[1-9]|3[01]|10|20)$`

---

*So kindly consider the following solution...*

**1. Identify the sets that need to be matched:**

- Days with prefix "0": `{01,...,09},{10,...,31}`

  - Sub-set `{10,...,31}` can be split into `=> {10,...,29},{30,31}`
- Without any prefix: `{1,...,31} => {1,...,9},{10,...,31}`

**2. Corresponding regular expressions for each sub-set:**

```
---------------------------------
Sub-Set     |  Regular-Expression
---------------------------------
{01,...,09} | [0][1-9]
{10,...,29} | [1-2][0-9]
{30,31}     | 3[01]
{1,...,9}   | [1-9]
---------------------------------
```

Now we can group `([0][1-9])` and `([1-9])` together as `([0]?[1-9])`. Where `?` signifies 0 or 1 occurrences of the pattern/symbol. ***[UPDATE]*** - Thank you  @MattFrear for pointing it out.

So the resulting RegEx is: `^(([0]?[1-9])|([1-2][0-9])|(3[01]))$`

Tested here: http://regexr.com/?383k1 **[UPDATE]**

Comment: Top marks for the explanation. The original question isn't worded particularly well (not the OPs fault) but if you're looking for REGEXP to validate a day of the month this is it.

Comment: An improvement over the accepted answer. However, this will accept 001, 00000001, etc. I suggest ^(([0]?[1-9])|([1-2][0-9])|(3[01]))$ http://regexr.com?383k1

Comment: @MattFrear - Yes good catch! I made a mistake while combining `([0][1-9])` and `([1-9])` together as `([0]*[1-9])`... while it should clearly be `([0]?[1-9])`. Thank you for sharing the test case.

Answer (score 14):

```
use DateTime;
```

Other solutions are fine, probably work, etc.  Usually, you end up wanting to do a bit more, and then a bit more, and eventually you have some crazy code, and leap years, and why are you doing it yourself again?

[DateTime](http://datetime.perl.org/wiki/datetime/dashboard) and its [formatters](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/DateTime-Format-Strptime-1.5000/lib/DateTime/Format/Strptime.pm) are your solution.  Use them!  Sometimes they are a bit overkill, but often that works out for you down the road.

```
my $dayFormat = new DateTime::Format::Strptime(pattern => '%d/%m/%Y');
my $foo = $dayFormat->parse_datetime($myDateString);
```

`$foo` is now a DateTime object.  Enjoy.

If your date string wasn't properly formatted, `$foo` will be `"undef"` and `$dayFormat->errstr` will tell you why.

Comment: I never understand why people want to reimplement anything let alone something as complicated as date parsing!

Answer (score 4):

```
^(((((((0?[13578])|(1[02]))[\.\-/]?((0?[1-9])|([12]\d)|(3[01])))|(((0?[469])|(11))[\.\-/]?((0?[1-9])|([12]\d)|(30)))|((0?2)[\.\-/]?((0?[1-9])|(1\d)|(2[0-8]))))[\.\-/]?(((19)|(20))?([\d][\d]))))|((0?2)[\.\-/]?(29)[\.\-/]?(((19)|(20))?(([02468][048])|([13579][26])))))$
```

From [Expressions in category: Dates and Times](http://regexlib.com/DisplayPatterns.aspx?cattabindex=4&categoryId=5)

Validates the correct number of days in a month, looks like it even handles leap years.

You can of course change `[\.\-/]` with `/` to only allow slashes.

Comment: +1 for a comical amount of complexity. @Zerobu, hopefully this shows you why regex is a bad idea for this problem! Even this beast isn't fully correct: as the original author notes, it incorrectly matches 02/29/1900.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't all *that* hard...

```
qr#^
    (?: 0[1-9] | 1[012] )
    /
    (?:
        0[1-9] | 1[0-9] | 2[0-8]
        | (?<! 0[2469]/ | 11/ ) 31
        | (?<! 02/ ) 30
        | (?<! 02/
             (?= ... 
                 (?: 
                     .. (?: [02468][1235679] | [13579][01345789] )
                     | (?: [02468][1235679] | [13579][01345789] ) 00
                 )
             )
        ) 29
    )
    /
    [0-9]{4}
    \z
#x
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check for valid dates, you have to do much more than check numbers and ranges. Fortunately, Perl already has everything you need for this. The [Time::Piece](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece) module comes with Perl and can parse a date. It knows how to parse dates and do the first round of checks:

```
use v5.10;

use Time::Piece; # comes with Perl

my @dates = qw(
    01/06/2021 01/37/456 10/6/1582 10/18/1988
    2/29/1900 2/29/1996 2/29/2000
    );

foreach my $date ( @dates ) {
    my $t = eval { Time::Piece->strptime( $date, '%m/%d/%Y' ) };
    unless( $t ) {
        say "Date <$date> is not valid";
        next;
        }
    say $t;
    }
```

The output is interesting and no other solution here is close to handling this. Why is 10/6/1582 an invalid date? It doesn't exist in the Gregorian calendar, but there's a simpler reason here. `strptime` doesn't handle dates before 1900.

But also notice that `2/29/1900` gets turned into `3/1/1900`. That's weird and we should fix that, but there's no leap years in years divisible by 100. Well, unless they are divisible by 400, which is why `2/29/2000` works.

```
Wed Jan  6 00:00:00 2021
Date <01/37/456> is not valid
Date <10/6/1582> is not valid
Tue Oct 18 00:00:00 1988
Thu Mar  1 00:00:00 1900
Thu Feb 29 00:00:00 1996
Tue Feb 29 00:00:00 2000
```

But let's fix that leap year issue. The `tm` struct is going a dumb conversion. If the individual numbers are within a reasonable range (0 to 31 for days) regardless of the month, then it converts those days to seconds and adds them to the offset. That's why 2/29/1900 ends up a day later: that 29 gives the same number of seconds as 3/1/1900. If the date is valid, it should come back the same. And since I'm going to roundtrip this, I fix up the date for leading zeros before I do anything with it:

```
use v5.10;

use Time::Piece; # comes with Perl

my @dates = qw(
    01/06/2021 2/29/1900 2/2/2020
    );

foreach my $date ( @dates ) {
    state $format = '%m/%d/%Y';
    $date =~ s/\b(\d)\b/0$1/g;  # add leading zeroes to lone digits
    my $t = eval { Time::Piece->strptime( $date, $format ) };
    unless( $t ) {
        say "Date <$date> is not valid";
        next;
        }
    unless( $t->strftime( $format ) eq $date ) {
        say "Round trip failed for <$date>: Got <"
            . $t->strftime( $format ) . ">";
        next;
        };
    say $t;
    }
```

Now the output is:

```
Wed Jan  6 00:00:00 2021
Round trip failed for <02/29/1900>: Got <03/01/1900>
Sun Feb  2 00:00:00 2020
```

That's all a bit long, but that's why we have subroutines:

```
if( date_is_valid( $date ) ) { ... }
```

Still want a regex? Okay, lets use the `(??{...})` construct to decide if a pattern should fail. Match a bunch of digits and capture that into `$1`. Now, use `(??{...})` to make the next part of the pattern, using any Perl code you like. If you accept the capture, return a null pattern. If you reject it, return the pattern `(*FAIL)`, which immediately causes the whole match to fail. No more tricky alternations. And this one uses the new [chained comparison in v5.32](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2020/03/chain-comparisons-to-avoid-excessive-typing/) (although I still have misgivings about it):

```
use v5.32;

foreach ( qw(-1 0 1 37 31 5 ) ) {
    if( /\A(\d+)(??{ (1 <= $1 <= 31) ? '' : '(*FAIL)' })\z/ ) {
        say "Value <$1> is between 1 and 31";
        }
    }
```

Comment: See also: http://blogs.perl.org/users/e_choroba/2019/12/perl-weekly-challenge-038-date-finder-and-word-game.html

Answer (score 1):

Try it:
`/(0?[1-9]|1[012])\/(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\/((19|20)\d\d)/`

Answer (score 1):

Is regular expression a must? If not, you better off using a different approach, such as `DateTime::Format::DateManip`

```
my @dates = (
    '04/23/2009',
    '01/22/2010 6pm',
    'adasdas',
    '1010101/12312312/1232132'
);

for my $date ( @dates ) 
{
    my $date = DateTime::Format::DateManip->parse_datetime( $date );
    die "Bad Date $date"  unless (defined $date);
    print "$dt\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Regex for 0-31 day:

0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]) without prefix 0 - when "1", "23"...

([1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]) with prefix 0 - when "01", "04"

(0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])  - with or without "0" - when ""

Comment: I think your first two regexes should be other way round.

Answer (score 1):

Simpler regex:

```
([12]\d|3[01]|0?[1-9])
```

Consider the accepted answer and this expression:

```
(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])
```

This matches 01 but not 1

The other expression in the accepted answer:

```
([1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])
```

This matches 1 but not 01

It is not possible to add an OR clause to get them both working.

The one I suggested matches both. Hope this helps.

Comment: How is this better than accepted answer (that you've copied/pasted°?

Comment: The accepted answer uses two different expressions to deal with days beginning with 0 or not. This one takes care of both in one expression. The behavior is similar to Kent Pawar's answer but the expression is much simpler. Also I couldn't plugin Kent's expression into another expression where I was trying to create regex for say YYMMDD etc

Comment: Can you please put the explanation as to why this is a better in the body of your answer?

Comment: OP says `MM` and "_this_ _matches_ _1_ _but_ _not_ _01_". Do note that to fit `MM` it should not match `1` and should match `01` instead

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for and in a very concise form.  Accepts 01 and 1.  Very good, ignore the haters.  :-)   Accepted answer doesn't do both.

Answer (score -1):

I have been working with this some time and the best regex I've came up with is the following:

```
\b(0)?(?(1)[1-9]|(3)?(?(2)[01]|[12][0-9]))\b|\b[1-9]\b
```

It will match the following numbers:

```
1 01 10 15 20 25 30 31
```

It does not match the following:

```
32 40 50 90
```

Comment: The OP problem is totally different to what this answer tries to answer

Comment: @bradbury9 the question wants a regex to match a number in the range 1-31, that's exactly what this answer claims to do, isn't it?

Comment: I think that this pattern is quite accurate on plausible different situations. You may find days written as 01 or 1 in different contexts. Let's say when writing dates (E.g: 01/02/2019) or in more formal documents... etc.