# Regex date matching not working

Tags: regex, perl, matching

I have a problem with my regex. Here it is.

```
/0[1-9]|1[0-2]|^[1-9]{1}$\/^[1-9]{1}$|0[1-9]|[1-2]\d|3[0-1]\/19\d{2}|20\d{2}/
```

It should not match this date,

```
1/32/2006
```

but for some reason it is matching, can you tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: For regex, it's usually better to tell us the conditions you're trying to match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would seem to have several problems.

The regex is matching "06" (from 2006) in the very first alternative you have listed "0[1-9]"

You probably meant

```
/^(0[1-9]|1[0-2]|^[1-9]{1})\/([1-9]{1}|0[1-9]|[1-2]\d|3[0-1])\/(19\d{2}|20\d{2})$/
```

or something like that (I have not tested that regex and it probably has other problems remaining), but you should really look at [Regular Expression to match a valid day in a date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6076979/regular-expression-to-match-a-valid-day-in-a-date) to see a better regexp and words to the wise about doing stuff like this in a regex.

Answer (score 2):

This is interesting:

```
^[1-9]{1}$
```

It looks like you're using that to match a digit that's not preceded or followed by another digit.  That won't work.  `^` and `$` anchor the match to the beginning and end of the string, and `{1}` does nothing at all.

If you want to allow for a single-digit number with an optional leading zero, use this:

```
0?[1-9]
```

The full regex would then be:

```
(?:1[02]|0?[1-9])\/(?:3[01]|[12]\d|0?[1-9])\/(?:19\d{2}|20\d{2})
```

I've also added parentheses for grouping, as @Seth suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You need to group the sections and get rid of the `^` and `$`.

```
/(0[1-9]|1[0-2]|[1-9]{1})\/([1-9]{1}|0[1-9]|[1-2]\d|3[0-1])\/((19|20)\d{2})/
```

Comment: Looks like Seth updated his answer quicker than I wrote (and tested) mine. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Even with all the spacing and the better delimiter,

```
m{
    ^
    (?: 0[1-9] | 1[0-2]? | [2-9] )
    /
    (?: 0[1-9] | 1[0-9]? | 2[0-9]? | 3[0-1]? | [4-9] )
    /
    (?: (?:19|20)[0-9]{2} )
    \z
}x
```

is not nearly as readable as

```
m{ ^ ([0-9]{1,2}) / ([0-9]{1,2}) / ([0-9]{4}) \z }x
    && $1 >=    1 && $1 <=   12
    && $2 >=    1 && $2 <=   31
    && $3 >= 1900 && $3 <= 2099
```

I've applied some fixes:

1. `\d` is not equivalent to `[0-9]`.
2. `$` allows for a newline.
3. I avoided needless captures (since the original didn't have them).

Answer (score 0):

There is a good overview of regular expressions matching dates [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dates.html). In particular, it lists this regular expression for matching MM/DD/YYYY dates:

```
^(0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)\d\d$
```