# Regular expression with own format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, format

I've tried to validate a own format (day,day,number,number) in my Ruby-Controller. The day has always two numbers (4-> 04). What i tried is the following:

```
... format: { with: /\A(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]){2}\p{L}{2}\z/, message: "wrong format" }
```

`(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])` comes from https://stackoverflow.com/a/6077026. This should validate the day. Then i add `{2}` because i want exactly two of these day-inputs. Finally `\p{L}` with `{2}` for two letters.

Does anyone know what i do wrong?

`3131zz` should be accepted. `3231zz` not.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you come to the conclusion, that your format does not work? If I validate it using rubular it works: [rubular example](http://rubular.com/r/ETY1JrXMVL)
If you are having trouble, I feel it is not with your regular expression but either with your input string being wrong or maybe some other validation which fails.

Comment: I finally found my error. I missed something that i later wrote to stackoverflow. Thanks anyhow.

Answer (score 1):

I have put your regular expression on : http://rubular.com/

And 3131zz is accepted whereas 3231zz is not... so it seems that your regex is correct.

What kind of error do you have?