# Getting error when using Date::Format

Tags: perl

I would like to convert `2003-07-04T15:56:00` to `04/07-2003` so I do

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use Date::Format;
use Data::Dumper;

my $time_format = "%d/%m-%Y";
my $time = "2003-07-04T15:56:00";

print Dumper time2str($time_format, $time);
```

and get

```
Argument "2003-07-04T15:56:00" isn't numeric in localtime at /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/Date/Format.pm line 123.
$VAR1 = '01/01-1970';
```

Any idea how to do this date convertion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DateTime::Format::Strptime
    ->new(pattern => '%FT%T')
    ->parse_datetime('2003-07-04T15:56:00')
    ->strftime('%d/%m-%Y')

# returns 04/07-2003
```

Answer (score 3):

The error message is spot on: `time2str` expects a numeric date representation, but got the string `"2003-07-04T15:56:00"`.

There are most likely several ways to resolve this. One of them is [Time::Local](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Local.html), that can help you create a proper numeric date.

Try to replace

```
my $time = "2003-07-04T15:56:00";
```

with:

```
my $time = timelocal(0,56,15,4,7-1,2003);
```

As @Jorik pointed out, month specification is a little unusual:

> It is worth drawing particular
>   attention to the expected ranges for
>   the values provided. The value for the
>   day of the month is the actual day (ie
>   1..31), *while the month is the number of months since January (0..11)*. This
>   is consistent with the values returned
>   from localtime() and gmtime().

**Edit**
For generic solutions to dates in strings check out the answers to this question: [How can I parse dates and convert time zones in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/411740/how-can-i-parse-dates-and-convert-time-zones-in-perl).

Comment: Small but significant comment (1 month ;). The original string probably refers to the 4th of July, whereas the arguments to timelocal would refer to the 4th of August (0..11)!

Comment: The thing is, that get the dates in `2003-07-04T15:56:00` format, so should I just regex to get it to `dd/mm-yyyy` or does there exist a way to this for me?

Comment: Sandra: There are several solutions to that aswell, I've updated the answer with a link to an earlier question about this.