# How to parse string in perl having timezone of format GMT[+/-]hh:mm?

Tags: perl

I have a string of date and time of format: 
Day, Month DAY_OF_MONTH, Year HH:MM:SS AM/PM GMT[+/-]hh:mm .

But I am unable to parse it. I have used this:

```
Time::Piece->strftime($string, "%A, %B %d, %Y %I:%M:%S %p %Z%z");
```

I have converted the string into the format : Day, Month DAY_OF_MONTH, Year HH:MM:SS AM/PM [+/-]hhmm . But still its not working for me with

```
Time::Piece->strftime($string, "%A, %B %d, %Y %I:%M:%S %p %z");
```

The string is getting parsed but the time zone is not considered in the Time::Piece object as tzoffset is 0000 and the HH of the date has the same value as that in the string. Please anyone help.

Eg: String to be parsed: Friday, July 25, 2008 12:15:57 PM GMT-0700

Comment: Why not include an actual date string with your example?  Make it as easy as possible for people to help you.

Comment: So it's **double** colon between Time and Piece...

Comment: Oh yeah..
I have used Time::Piece only.  double colon between Time and Piece
Actually, I am not getting the error, the string is getting parsed successfully, but when I print it, the tzoffset have hours and minutes as 0000 and the hours of the Time::Piece object is still 12.
But in v 5.16 it is 19 with tzoffest 0000.

So, the thing is that it is parsing but the timezone, but the timezone is not in the Time::Piece object.
Any other way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If Time::Piece doesn't work, try using [Date::Parse](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Date%3A%3AParse).

And as oalders mentioned, do include an actual date string example in your question.

Comment: Hi, I am using Perl v 5.10, and it doesn't have Date::Parse.
Eg : Actual string to parse is : Friday, July 25, 2008 12:15:57 PM GMT-07:00 . Which I converted into Friday, July 25, 2008 12:15:57 PM -0700 . It is working in v 5.16 and not in v 5.10.
Please help.

Comment: Install it from CPAN? One of the main reasons to use Perl is CPAN's 20,000 modules. `cpan Date::Parse`.

Comment: I am forced to use v 5.10 and can not install any new packages. :(

Comment: @user1799308, not being able to use CPAN is a ridiculous restriction. You can either use it and solve your problem in 15 minutes, or not use it and spend a week coming to, more often than not, an inferior solution.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the following will help:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::Piece;

my $string = 'Sunday, November 4, 2012 10:25:15 PM -0000';
my $t = Time::Piece->strptime( $string, "%A, %B %d, %Y %I:%M:%S %p %z" );
print $t;
```

Output:

```
Sun Nov  4 22:25:15 2012
```

Comment: Actually, this piece of code works in Perl v 5.16 but not in 5.10.
And I am forced to use version 5.10 without installing any packages.
Please help.

Comment: @user1799380 - Time::Piece was around before Perl v5.10.

Comment: yeah.. it is there, but there is problem with the timezone.

Comment: @user1799380 - Maybe the following thread will help: [How can I parse dates and convert time zones in Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/411740/how-can-i-parse-dates-and-convert-time-zones-in-perl)

Comment: Note that the function you want to call has a 'p' in it rather than an 'f'. strptime is not the same as strftime.

Comment: @titanofold - Perhaps I'm missing something, as [the documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~jhi/perl-5.7.2/ext/Time/Piece/Piece.pm) shows that Time::Piece supports the %p token.  In fact, the documentation states that "The available format characters [for Time::Piece] are as in the standard strftime() function..."