# How to convert unknown date/time format into normal using Perl?

Tags: perl, datetime, format, iso8601, strptime

I have a date/time like this: 2015-07-31T13:30:00.000+01:00
And I want to convert it to normal date and time using Perl and Time::Piece->strptime

Here is my code:

```
sub changeDateFormat {
  my ($date, $fromFormat, $toFormat) = (@_);
  return Time::Piece->strptime($date, $fromFormat)->strftime($toFormat);
}
```

The call:

```
print changeDateFormat($that_date, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%N+%z', '%Y:%m:%d');
```

I think that .000 are nano seconds and +01.00 stands for time zone.
But the given code gives this: 
*Error parsing time at /usr/lib64/perl5/Time/Piece.pm line 470*

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: See [`DateTime::Format::Strptime`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime::Format::Strptime).. It has both `%N` and `%z`..

Comment: The format is known as a ISO 8601 calendar date and time of day with a zone designator in extended format. [Time::Moment->from_string](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Time-Moment/lib/Time/Moment.pod#from_string) can be used to parse it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of problems I think.

`%N` isn't in my [`strftime`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html) manpage. So that might well not work.

And `%z` - I'm pretty sure `+01:00` isn't valid.

> ```
>   %z     The +hhmm or -hhmm numeric timezone (that is, the hour and
>           minute offset from UTC). (SU)
> ```

This works though:

```
my $date = '2015-07-31T13:30:00+0100'; 
my $fromFormat = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'; 
print Time::Piece->strptime($date, $fromFormat);
```

So I'd suggest - unless your milliseconds are important - you could just strip those via a regex, and likewise the timezone. (And it they are important, I don't think `Time::Piece` does ms resolution anyway)

You can probably use a regular expression to 'correct' your input date if you were so inclined. I'm unsure if fits your use case but:

```
$date =~ s/\+(\d{2}):(\d{2})$/+$1$2/;
$date =~ s/\.\d{3}+/+/;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `strptime` in `Time::Piece` and adding the time zone manually as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/411795/2173773), or you could try using  [`DateTime::Format::Strptime`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime::Format::Strptime) instead:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;
use DateTime::Format::Strptime;

my $timestamp = '2015-07-31T13:30:00.000+0100';
my $strp = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
    pattern   => '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%N%z'
);

my $dt = $strp->parse_datetime( $timestamp );

say $dt->strftime('%Y:%m:%d');
```

Output:

```
2015:07:31
```

Comment: Does `%N` work in that one then?

Answer (score 1):

```
use DateTime; 
use DateTime::Format::ISO8601;

use DateTime::Format::Strptime;

my $string = '2015-07-31T13:30:00.000+01:00';
my $date = DateTime::Format::ISO8601->parse_datetime( $string ); 
die "Error" unless $date;

my $formatter = new DateTime::Format::Strptime(pattern => '%Y-%m-%d %T');
$date->set_formatter($formatter);
print "$date\n";
```