# How to convert epoch time to UTC time using Perl?

Tags: perl, datetime, epoch

I need to convert epoch date and time string to UTC date and time using Perl.

Kindly share your thoughts.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my $start_time='1448841600';
my $stop_time='1448863200';
```

The above two date and times are in epoch format and those should be converted to UTC date and time.

Comment: My first thought is "why are those numbers in quoted strings?" :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `gmtime` to do the conversion, and `strftime` to do the formatting.

```
  use POSIX 'strftime';

  strftime "%d-%m-%Y-%H:%M:%S", gmtime('1448841600');
```

Comment: Coordinated Universal Time (abbreviated as UTC, also called Greenwich Mean Time or GMT) is returned by [gmtime](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/gmtime.html). So instead of `localtime` you should use `gmtime`.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest using the [`Time::Piece`](http://search.cpan.org/~esaym/Time-Piece-1.31/Piece.pm) module for manipulating dates.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::Piece;

my $start_time=Time::Piece -> new(1448841600);


print $start_time,"\n";
print $start_time -> epoch,"\n";
print $start_time -> strftime ( "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" ),"\n";

#nb - you can also use localtime/gmtime:
my $end_time = gmtime(1448863200);
print $end_time,"\n";
print $end_time->epoch,"\n";
```

You can also do timezone maths as outlined here: [How can I parse dates and convert time zones in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/411740/how-can-i-parse-dates-and-convert-time-zones-in-perl)

Answer (score 3):

Use [gmtime](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/gmtime.html) to get the UTC time.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to do more manipulations on those datetime, [use DateTime](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/DateTime-1.21/lib/DateTime.pm)

```
use DateTime;
my $start_time ='1448841600';
my $stop_time  ='1448863200';
my $start = DateTime->from_epoch(epoch=>$start_time)->set_time_zone('UTC');
my $stop  = DateTime->from_epoch(epoch=>$stop_time)->set_time_zone('UTC');
say $start->strftime("%F %T %Z");  # 2015-11-30 00:00:00 UTC
say $stop->strftime("%F %T %Z");   # 2015-11-30 06:00:00 UTC
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [gmtime](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlport.html#gmtime) function:

```
my $time = "1448841600";
my @months = ("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec");
my ($sec, $min, $hour, $day,$month,$year) = (gmtime($time))[0,1,2,3,4,5]; 
print "Time ".$time." converts to ".$months[$month]." ".$day.", ".($year+1900);
print " ".$hour.":".$min.":".$sec."\n";
```

Output:

```
Time 1448841600 converts to Nov 30, 2015 0:0:0
```

Answer (score 1):

`perl -E 'say scalar gmtime(1638884356)'`

same for localtime