# Converting timestamps in Perl

Tags: perl

I am looking to convert timestamps such as the following

2019-01-01T02:15:00+00:00

Into Australian Eastern Standard Time in Perl.
I have over 10,000 of these timestamps, any help would be really appreciated
I need to input them into a mysql DB with a format of YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss

Comment: What is the the database field data type? Is it DATETIME or TIMESTAMP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use the standard Perl module [Time::Piece](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece).  It provides the standard `strptime` and `strftime` functions.  The first allows you to parse a timestamp with a template and the second outputs a timestamp based on the same kind of template.  To change timezones you would add or subtract the number of seconds difference.

```perl
$t = Time::Piece->strptime("2020-11-04T01:46:00", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S");
$t += $offset;
print $t->strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S");
```

Or if your current time is the current locale and you're always converting from GMT:

```perl
$t = Time::Piece->strptime("2020-11-04T01:46:00", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S");
$l = localtime $t->epoch;
print $l->strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S");
```

Now if you need to do something more complicated than that (daylight savings time, leap seconds), there is the [DateTime](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime) module but it is correspondingly far more complicated to use.

See also [How can I parse dates and convert time zones in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/411740/how-can-i-parse-dates-and-convert-time-zones-in-perl?rq=1)

HTH