# How can I calculate the age of a person in year, month, days in PHP?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I calculate the age of a person in year, month, days?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453208/how-can-i-calculate-the-age-of-a-person-in-year-month-days)

I want to calculate the age of a person given the date of birth and the current date in years, months and days relative to the current date.

For example:

```
>>> calculate_age(2008, 01, 01)
1 years, 0 months, 16 days
```

Comment: Take a look at this Stack overflow post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php

Comment: There is several question in the Related Section to the right asking the very same and I am pretty sure you have been shown suggestions when you entered your question. Dont ask superfluous duplicates please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');

function findage($dob)
{
    $localtime = getdate();
    $today = $localtime['mday']."-".$localtime['mon']."-".$localtime['year'];
    $dob_a = explode("-", $dob);
    $today_a = explode("-", $today);
    $dob_d = $dob_a[0];$dob_m = $dob_a[1];$dob_y = $dob_a[2];
    $today_d = $today_a[0];$today_m = $today_a[1];$today_y = $today_a[2];
    $years = $today_y - $dob_y;
    $months = $today_m - $dob_m;
    if ($today_m.$today_d < $dob_m.$dob_d) 
    {
        $years--;
        $months = 12 + $today_m - $dob_m;
    }

    if ($today_d < $dob_d) 
    {
        $months--;
    }

    $firstMonths=array(1,3,5,7,8,10,12);
    $secondMonths=array(4,6,9,11);
    $thirdMonths=array(2);

    if($today_m - $dob_m == 1) 
    {
        if(in_array($dob_m, $firstMonths)) 
        {
            array_push($firstMonths, 0);
        }
        elseif(in_array($dob_m, $secondMonths)) 
        {
            array_push($secondMonths, 0);
        }elseif(in_array($dob_m, $thirdMonths)) 
        {
            array_push($thirdMonths, 0);
        }
    }
    echo "<br><br> Age is $years years $months months.";
}

findage("21-04-1969"); //put date in the dd-mm-yyyy format
?>
```

Comment: thank you 
but i need  days also :)

Answer (score 32):

You can use PHP `date_diff` http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php or http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php to achieve what you want  and you can output it in any format you want using `PHP` date format

```
$interval = date_diff(date_create(), date_create('2008-01-01 10:30:00'));
echo $interval->format("You are  %Y Year, %M Months, %d Days, %H Hours, %i Minutes, %s Seconds Old");
```

echo

```
You are 04 Year, 04 Months, 1 Days, 00 Hours, 56 Minutes, 36 Seconds Old
```

Comment: where is the function definition for date_diff() ? i'm getting the error
**Fatal error: Call to undefined function date_diff()**

Comment: see http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php & http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Comment: Finally found what i wanted exactly +1!

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$ageTime = mktime(0, 0, 0, 9, 9, 1919); // Get the person's birthday timestamp
$t = time(); // Store current time for consistency
$age = ($ageTime < 0) ? ( $t + ($ageTime * -1) ) : $t - $ageTime;
$year = 60 * 60 * 24 * 365;
$ageYears = $age / $year;

echo 'You are ' . floor($ageYears) . ' years old.';
?>
```

[Source](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/19953-calculating-age-tutorial/)

Comment: thank you for your effort
but i need it in years, months and days

Comment: Wasn't my effort, if you look at the source ;)

Comment: i say that
i need it in years, months and days

Answer (score 0):

Use datatime diff function

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php