# How to convert date time to Unix timestamp using Perl

Tags: perl

I have a date time displayed as `06 August 2012 21:02:00` and need to convert it to a Unix timestamp using Perl.

Comment: It doesn't matter to me if it's basic.  What matters to me is that the OP didn't show any code to demonstrate what he has tried, didn't explain how that attempt failed, didn't show any research, didn't elaborate on any thoughts he already has of how to solve it himself first, and essentially showed no effort.  Basic is fine.  But this isn't a code-writing service, and a little effort needs to go into questions to show that we're not being treated as such.

Comment: @pavel - basic questions are not against SO rules.

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/95492/how-do-i-convert-a-date-time-to-epoch-time-aka-unix-time-seconds-since-1970?rq=1

Comment: I am surprised at the closure of this question, especially from @briandfoy. A call of *duplicate* may have been appropriate, but *not constructive* is bizarre.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to stay with core modules, use `Time::Piece` (available in Perl 5.10 on):

```
use Time::Piece;
my $t = Time::Piece->strptime(shift,"%d %B %Y %H:%M:%S");
print $t->epoch, "\n";

./mypl "06 August 2012 21:02:00"
1344286920
```

Answer (score 6):

```
use Date::Parse; 
print str2time('06 August 2012 21:02:00');
```