# Process start timestamp on macOS

Tags: macos, shell, unix

How can I get the start time of a process on macOS? `ps -o lstart` and `ps -o start` print formatted dates instead of a Unix timestamp.

Ideally this would be portable across Unix (i.e. no `/proc` obviously).

Answer (score 1):

`lstart` uses the format specified by the locale, and if you use `LC_ALL=C`, you can get a consistent, simple format:

```
$ TZ=UTC LC_TIME=C ps -o lstart= -p $$
Thu May 11 01:03:52 2017
$ LC_TIME=C ps -o lstart= -p $$
Thu May 11 10:03:52 2017
```

Then there are several tools that can be used to convert the formatted date to a timestamp. For portability, [perhaps Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11835456/2072269):

```
$ (export LC_TIME=C TZ=UTC; ps -o lstart= -p $$ | perl -ne 'use Date::Parse; printf "%s\n", str2time($_)')
1494882318
```

Comment: Does this handle DST issues and anything else I'm not thinking of? It would seem like it would be confused on the "fall back" hour, since there are two possible timestamps for a natural language date in that case.

Comment: @taway if timezones could be a problem, you could set `TZ` to `UTC` as well