# Parsing time stamps and calculating difference

Tags: perl

So I am parsing a log file and look for certain time stamps and then subtracting  them to get time elapsed.

So I tried a simple code to see if I can use Time::Piece but wasnt successful. My code below:

```
use Time::Piece;

my ($S, $E);

GetOptions (
    "S=s" => \$S,
    "E=s" => \$E,
    );

my $start    = $S;
my $end = $E;
my %build_time;

my $start_time;
my $end_time;
if(my ($start_time) = $start =~ /\[gg\s+(\d+\:\d+\:\d+)\s+I\]/){
    print"Build_Time: start at $start_time\n";
}
#--------------------
# End time from dj
if(my ($end_time) = $end =~ /\[gg\s+(\d+\:\d+\:\d+)\s+I\]/){
    print "Build_Time: end at $end_time\n";
}

my $difference = Time::Piece->strptime($end_time,'%H:%M:%S') - Time::Piece->strptime($start_time,'%H:%M:%S');

print " difference: $difference \n";
```

Execute:
perl time.pl -S "[gg 8:11:03 I]: Copyright" -E "[gg 8:19:03 I]:  BT_DEPTH=99 "

Build_Time: start at 8:11:03
Build_Time: end at 8:19:03
difference: 0

Also what is the time is in 24 hr format and log contains over night run ( so the difference would be negative)?

Comment: So you don't have a date at all, just time?  Indeed, what if it crosses into another day? How do you tell whether it's morning or evening? Can it be multiple days?

Comment: Perhaps what you are looking for is answered in [Q95492](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95492/how-do-i-convert-a-date-time-to-epoch-time-unix-time-seconds-since-1970-in-per). As it was indicated you need not just time but a complete date.

Comment: No date.. the log seems to go from 0 to 24 and then revert back to 0. I can put a constraint on not crossing multiple days but I have to cover 24 hours. If someone kicks of the run overnight and then in the morning they will expect an email with run stats.

Answer (score 3):

Your code has a scoping issue: `$start_time` and `$end_time` in your `if` statements mask the outer variables.
If the time difference is 23:59:59 max you can use a modulo operation to fix the negative seconds output caused by crossing a date boundary:

time.pl:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Long;

use Time::Piece;
my ($S, $E);

GetOptions (
    "S=s" => \$S,
    "E=s" => \$E,
    );

my $start    = $S;
my $end = $E;
my %build_time;

my $start_time;
my $end_time;
if( ($start_time) = $start =~ /\[gg\s+(\d+\:\d+\:\d+)\s+I\]/){
    print"Build_Time: start at $start_time\n";
}
#--------------------
# End time from dj
if( ($end_time) = $end =~ /\[gg\s+(\d+\:\d+\:\d+)\s+I\]/){
    print "Build_Time: end at $end_time\n";
}

my $tp_st = Time::Piece->strptime($start_time,'%H:%M:%S');
my $tp_e =  Time::Piece->strptime($end_time,'%H:%M:%S');

my $difference = $tp_e -$tp_st;
$difference %= 60*60*24; # 1 day
print " difference: $difference \n";
```

testing:

```
perl time.pl -S "[gg 8:19:04 I]: Copyright" -E "[gg 8:19:14 I]: BT_DEPTH=99 "
Build_Time: start at 8:19:04
Build_Time: end at 8:19:14
 difference: 10 


perl time.pl -S "[gg 8:19:04 I]: Copyright" -E "[gg 8:19:03 I]: BT_DEPTH=99 "
Build_Time: start at 8:19:04
Build_Time: end at 8:19:03
 difference: 86399
```

Comment: I copied your code and ran and I am still seeing that difference is 0. I printed out the variables $tp_st and $tp_e and here are their values                                                                                                       $tp_st = Thu Jan  1 00:00:00 1970

Comment: I tried this :  ( another answer I found on the website) 
my $str1 = 'Execution started at 05/25/2011 05:22:03 PM';
my $str2 = 'Execution completed at 05/25/2011 05:34:08 PM';

my @times = map Time::Piece->strptime(/(\d.+M)/, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p'), $str1, $str2;

my $delta = $times[1] - $times[0];    The problem here is that this code doesnt work if Hours are represented as 24 hr format and if PM/AM arent present.  I tried removing %p from the equation but that just didnt compile

Comment: I don't believe you copied my code. Did you add `use strict; use warnings;` ? Did you remove the `my` from both your `if` -statenments?

Comment: I copied it on a separate file word to word.... and executed it! I am not sure why my $tp_st = Time::Piece->strptime($start_time,'%H:%M:%S'); is giving back Thu Jan  1 00:00:00 1970

Comment: Check what you have in `$start_time` before calling `strptime()`

Comment: It works now!. Sorry, $start_time had a typo that I passed through command line and it didnt work well with the match command. Thanks again for your help

Answer (score 2):

If input is indeed limited to times within 24 hours then if start time is *larger* than end time it means it rolled into another day.  So you can substract `Time::Piece` objects and adjust if negative

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use Getopt::Long;
use Time::Piece;

GetOptions ( "S=s" => \my $S, "E=s" => \my $E );

my ($tp_beg, $tp_end) = map { 
    my ($time) = /\[gg\s+ ([0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+) \s+ I\]/x;
    die "Unexpected input format ($_)" if not $time;
    Time::Piece->strptime($time, "%H:%M:%S")
} $S, $E;

my $diff_secs = $tp_end - $tp_beg;
$diff_secs += 24*60*60  if $diff_secs < 0;

say "Difference is $diff_secs secs";

say "Difference is ", sec_in_day_to_hms($diff_secs);

sub sec_in_day_to_hms {  # add ($tt >= 3600*24) branch for multiple days
    my ($tt) = @_;
    my $msg = do {
        if ( $tt >= 3600 ) {
            sprintf("%d:%02d:%02d (hr:min:sec)",
                $tt/3600, ($tt%3600)/60, $tt%60);
        }
        elsif ( $tt >= 60 ) {
            sprintf("%d min %d sec", ($tt%3600)/60, $tt%60);
        } 
        else { sprintf("%d sec", $tt%60); }
    };
    return $msg;
}
```

Running as in the question

```
perl time_diff.pl -S "[gg 8:11:03 I]: Copyright" -E "[gg 8:19:03 I]: BT_DEPTH=99 "
```

prints

```
Difference is 480 secs
Difference is 8 min 0 sec
```

If we change `8:19:03` to `6:19:03` (so it rolled all the way by about two hours short of a full day) and run it as

```
perl time_diff.pl -S "[gg 8:11:03 I]: Copyright" -E "[gg 6:19:03 I]: BT_DEPTH=99 "
```

then it prints

```
Difference is 79680 secs
Difference is 22:08:00 (hr:min:sec)
```

---

*A comment on the code in the question*

It firstly has a mistake of defining a variable `$start_time` *also* inside an `if` block

```
if(my ($start_time) = $start =~ /.../){
```

and that variable masks (shadows) the one with the same name declared earlier.  After the `if` block is exited, the earlier `$start_time` is restored, um, to `undef`.

When that's used later in the program (for subtraction) *it would print warnings* -- if you had them on!  Please add

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

to the top of every program.  These are directly helpful.

One simple way to fix that would be to just remove that `my` -- then the regex's return is assigned indeed to the earlier declared `$start_time`.  However, I find that there are too many variables introduced for the purpose so I'd suggest to simplify instead.

Then, the possibly negative difference isn't handled, what the question itself asserts.

Comment: The issue is that this string  Time::Piece->strptime($time, "%H:%M:%S") gives back Thu Jan 1 00:00:00 1970

Comment: @PublicEmail Did you actually run this?  It's a copy-pasted program.  I added a command and its output

Comment: @PublicEmail Explanation: What you get out of `Time::Piece->strptime` is a `Time::Piece` _object_, and if you print that it gets "stringified" into what you quote.  But, when you subtract two such objects then it does the job and returns seconds between them.

Comment: The issue in on my end. Other peers have suggested solutions and I cant reproduce. Nevertheless, I want to thank you for you help. I apologize if my remark sounded anything but sincere.

Comment: @PublicEmail That's OK, please do make remarks :)  But then can you not run it?  It doesn't use/do anything special?  I edited, with a function to convert secs to hh:mm:ss (just a user convenience) I'll edit for commentary.  All that I show as "prints..." comes directly copied from my terminal, from a program copied verbatim from what is posted.

Comment: @PublicEmail  "_The issue in on my end. ... I cant reproduce_" -- what Perl version do you have, what system are you running on?

Comment: It works! The issue was in the command line that I was passing.

Comment: @PublicEmail OK! :)  I edited further ...

Comment: @PublicEmail  Completed edits.  Let me know if there are questions